# How to change path from apache to nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

Our application running in Apache in Amazon Web  Services server but now i want to change to nginx server i already installed `nginx` but i don't know how  to give path i.e `/etc/www/html`  to `Ngix` what should i do?
I have ssh access to what i do should i change anything in server or any other solution.

**What am i do any thing possible solution for this?**

Comment: Looks like something went wrong when posting, as you have duplicated lines. You should edit your post.

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit some configuration files under /etc/nginx. The structure of the directories is similar to the one of Apache. However, the config files are different. Under there, you'll normally find a sites-available directory, and inside that directory a configuration file for your site. There might be multiple files or just one file in that directory depending on the number of sites you have. You'll have to find the right file for the site you want to modify. In that file, there is a root directive. For example, by default, it is as follows on my server:

```
root /var/www/html;
```

In your case, that would be

```
root /etc/www/html;
```

To tell you the truth, I find it a bit strange to have the www/html folder under /etc. What OS are you running on your server?

Also, you will need to set a symbolic link from your config file under sites-available into the sites-enabled directory. Both directories are under /etc/nginx. Once this is all done, you will need to restart nginx. On my Debian server, I use `service nginx restart`.

Of course, you`ll have to stop Apache listening on port 80 if you want Nginx to listen on that port.

Comment: I would like to know why the -1.